# Load last records first using for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

Right the data is loading in ascending order but I want to display the records in descending order.
I am using a for loop for getting 5 records at a time. 
I tired to reverse the for loop but the data still loads in ascending order.
Temp is where the json gets loaded from api.

Code:

```
 for (i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
   const row = resp.shift();
   $('#dataRow').append(getElement(row.name, row.id, row.address, row.time));
 }
```

I tried this but this din work, like it still loaded data in ascending order:

```
for (i = temp; i >0; i--)
```

I also tried `unshift` but that gives all records as undefined.

It would be good if data is loaded based on time. Most recent one first.

sample json:

```
"data":[
  {
    "name": "demo",
    "id":1,
    "address":"not available",
    "time":"2019-10-11 11:12:53"
  },
  {
    "name": "demo1",
    "id":2,
    "address":"not available",
    "time":"2019-10-11 11:12:59"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort `resp` by `time` in descending order first.

```
resp.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.time) - new Date(a.time))
```

Then iterate `resp` as normal.

Comment: This is the ideal solution. Works fine even when new records are added on button click

Answer (score 0):

Use prepend to insert as the first child, so the last one ends up before all the previous ones.

This is the only change you need to make:

```
$('#dataRow').prepend(getElement(row.name, row.id, row.address, row.time));
```

And just to demonstrate the reversed order:

```js
var resp = [
  '<div>one</div>',
  '<div>two</div>',
  '<div>three</div>',
  '<div>four</div>',
  '<div>five</div>',
];

$(resp).each(function() {
  $('#dataRow').prepend(this)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dataRow"></div>
```

Comment: This does not work when you show records on button click. It just adds 5 latest records on top but initially old records are only displayed